# Application runs out of Memory despite garbage collection and only 10mB RAM usage C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, out-of-memory, garbage

I try coding an Application that shows a slideshow with a picture box.
Loading a new image causes the application to run out of memory at some point. Even though i dispose the old images and manualy run GC. Task Explorer shows 10mB usage.

At first i saw the ram increase withouth the dispose function. Including the dispose kept the ram constant but still throws the out of memory exception at some point.

My code to load the next image and dispose the old one.
I needed to include the Application.DoEvents() because the UI Thread did not get updated

```
PictureBox.Image.Dispose();
PictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(currentfolder.ImageList[currentindex]);
Application.DoEvents();
currentindex++;
GC.Collect();
```

I cannot see any reason why i run out of memory. My System has 8GB and is running 57% usage at idle.

Comment: Are you certain all of the images you're trying to load are valid images? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromfile?view=netframework-4.8 `Image.FromFile` will throw an `OutOfMemoryException` if the format is invalid. Otherwise, `Application.DoEvents()` and manual invocation of the `GC` are probably not ideal solutions, but wouldn't necessarily cause this.

Comment: 10MB is awfully low.  But do keep in mind that this statistic is not meaningful for .NET programs and cannot predict an OOM exception.  Closest relevant number is "Private bytes", visible with Perfmon.exe.  Standard reasons for OOM from Image.FromFile() is a corrupted image file or the bitmap simply being too large to fit in the address space of a 32-bit process.  Since the latter is most likely, use Project > Properties > Build tab, untick "Prefer 32-bit".

Comment: Remove `Application.DoEvents();` and `GC.Collect();` (completely useless here). I don't see where you're checking whether the current index is past the list count. You should also have `PictureBox.Image?.Dispose();`, so you don't try to dispose a null object. If the problem is not what Hans Passant mentioned, you might have undisposed handles somewhere else. The main system memory is not the only memory type in play here.

Comment: Without an actual [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, no one can answer your question. That said, keep in mind that WinForms uses GDI+ for image handling, and will often throw an `OutOfMemoryException` for issues that are not in fact directly related to memory consumption (such as invalid or unsupported image files).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot. The Problem actually was that i had elements in the list that were no images. The out of Memory Exception really confused me. 
Thanks steve16351 and the others